# Two relationships between two models, one model have same relation 2 times, but with diferent names

Tags: laravel, eloquent, entity-relationship, eloquent-relationship

I have the following database schema:

[image: Database schema]

The following is intended for this scheme:

1 user can have several teams and a team can have up to two users (I assumed it is a many-to-many relationship and then I validate whether or not a team has only two users)

1 team can have multiple games and a game only has a home_team (team) and an away_team (team) here I assumed it will have two 1 to many relationships (1 team has multiple games and a game only has an away_team and a home_team).

My question is how should I make their relationships in the models, for example, to get through a user all his games, both away_team and home_team.

I try this:

```
public function awayTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'uuid');
}

public function homeTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'uuid');
}
```

Team Model

```
public function homeGames()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'uuid', 'home_team_uuid');
}

public function awayGames()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class,  'uuid', 'away_team_uuid');
}
```

User Model

```
public function teams()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class);
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please add your code.

Comment: Sorry, i add wht i tried in model, but not work, I have a user with several teams and some games and I can't get them to be returned

Answer (score 0):

O find the problem:

in Team model i need declare 'foreign_key' and 'local_key' like that, because i dont use convencional fields

```
public function homeGames()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class, 'home_team_uuid', 'uuid');
}

public function awayGames()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Game::class,  'away_team_uuid', 'uuid');
}
```

In Game model i change for that, for same reason:

```
public function awayTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'away_team_uuid', 'uuid');
}

public function homeTeam()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Team::class, 'home_team_uuid', 'uuid');
}
```

and now i can have relation response.